# Call RenderSection twice ...?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an ASP.NET-MVC3-Layout and use the RenderSection function:

```
@RenderSection("BackLink", required: false)
```

How can I call this function twice? I want to render a defined section at multiple places in my layout.

If I use `@RenderSection()` more than once I get an error.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
@var result = RenderSection("BackLink", required: false).ToHtmlString();

First:
@Html.Raw(result);

Second:
@Html.Raw(result);
```

Comment: Is there some other way to do this? According to the MS docs ToHtmlString() as used above should not be used directly in our code only by .NET infrastructure and thus they may change this.