# Html.Raw rendering outside of container div

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an ASP.NET MVC template using Bootstrap 3 that looks like this:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    var menu = RenderSection("menu", required: false).ToHtmlString();
}

@section scripts{
    @RenderSection("scripts", false)
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-10">
                @Html.Raw(menu)
                @*@RenderSection("menu")*@
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</div>
```

The reason for this is that I want to render the menu again for a mobile layout below the content.

Here's the issue: If I use the @RenderSection (which is commented out in the code above), it works as intended. If I use the @Html.Raw, the menu contents actually render outside of the top-level div.

The menu variable contains exactly the same HTML, but it's rendered in a different location.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: May be the size in ` class="col-sm-12 col-lg-10" ` doesn't suits for `.ToHtmlString();` in menu.

Comment: how have you checked if the menu variable contains the exact string? 
can you try a console.log?

Comment: Well, this is weird. To get where I was, I followed this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931104/call-rendersection-twice and the answer was accepted, so I assumed it would work for me.

As it turns out, the initial call to RenderSection in my code forces it to render right there, which is why it's outside of the <div>. I can't get it to work as in the linked example.